# Android: getRunningAppProcessInfo() is not working in 5.1.1

Tags: android, foreground

I am using below code to get running processes/apps in 5.1.1 android version.

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> allProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

In "allProcesses " i am getting only my app information.But I need all Process IDs running in device.
Can Somebody help me if there is any alternative solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it returns "a list of application processes that are running on the device.", not "Foregeound activity"

Comment: what is not working? Is tasks is null? or what else? Be more specific so that others can help

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my question. Please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

"Applications must now have ...permission.REAL_GET_TASKS to
be able to get process information for all applications. Only the process information for the calling application will be  returned if the app doesn't have the permission."

quote from https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2347

Comment: I have the permission. But still it returns the same. Finally I found out the issue. From 5.1.1 , android stops returning running process info using activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses(). I am using AccessibilityService. Please let me know if you have any other solution.

Comment: Others says something about using UsageStatsManager,I haven't try it yet.